# Is it possible to create a headless accessibility tool for windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, mobile-development

We've just successfully created an accessibility app for android (think screen reader) that works across all applications without needing to first launch a specific app, via the [accessibility service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html#manifest).

Is it possible to create an equivalent headless service for Windows Phone? UIAutomation is available for WinRT but I don't think it's available for Windows Phone 8.1 or 10 in the same way. How could I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's currently not possible to build a system-wide accessibility app on Windows Phone 8.x (or 10 for that matter). Please consider adding a suggestion [on UserVoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I absolutely will do that. We feel very spoiled with android, it is extremely mature and feature rich compared to other mobile platforms